# filename substitution -- is there something to make sure it is not a certain letters?

Tags: command-line, bash

What is the command for getting a filename with any character EXCEPT a few?

Say I do not want the filename to contain the letters q and Q

ls *[^qQ]* does not work. What would I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use globbing (it's not always a good idea), you can use:

```
$ ls -d !(*[qQ]*)
```

or with `shopt -s nocaseglob`:

```
$ shopt -s nocaseglob
$ ls -d !(*q*)
```

The `-d` option so as to not list the content of the matched directories.

For this to work you must have `extglob` set, it's probably the case by default. If not, `shopt -s extglob` will do.

A better approach would be to use *find*, as you'll be able to `-exec` some stuff on the matched files if you need (rename, *grep*, edit, etc...), and you'll have a much better control on what you need to match. An example:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 \! -iname '*q*' -type f
```

This will find all files (`-type f`) in current directory (`.`) not in subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`) that don't (`\!`) have a *q* or a *Q* in their name (`-iname '*q*'`).

If you have a huge number of files, *find* is better and faster than *Bash*'s globbing, and won't overflow the maximal number of arguments.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm ls -d !(*[qQ]*) appears to not work (-bash: !: event not found)   EDIT: Nvm I enabled extended globbing and it seems to be working :)

Answer (score 0):

If bash *extended globbing* is enabled, then you can invert matches with !(*pattern*) e.g. if

```
$ touch aQq qwerty uiop asdfg bnmq
$ 
$ ls
aQq  asdfg  bnmq  qwerty  uiop
```

then

```
$ ls !(*[qQ]*)
asdfg  uiop
```

whereas

```
$ ls *[qQ]*
aQq  bnmq  qwerty
```

You can check the current value of the extglob option using `shopt -p extglob` and set it with `shopt -s extglob`. Type `help shopt` at the bash prompt for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
ls | grep -v [qQ]
```

If instead of single characters you want to exclude file names containing certain *strings of charaters* you could do so with

```
ls | grep -v "str1\|str2\|..."
```

i.e. separating any string with the escaped pipe char `|` (which acts as an "OR" logical operator). Remember to enclose it in double quotes to prevent special characters to be misinterpreted.